# Database design to support several different applications

Tags: sql-server, api, database-design

I have a DB design question that I am hoping to get some opinions on.

The environment is MS SQL Server, with an API built using ASP.NET WEB API (and entity framework wherever possible)

The concept is that there are several different applications that will leverage an API. Each application is quite different in its functionality and data. However there are several different pieces of (lookup) data that are common across each application. One solution of course would be to have one gigantic database with many many tables which of course allows for referential integrity to be maintained but that just "feels" wrong to me because of each application being so different in its purpose.

The other option is to set up several different DBs. One for each application's specific data concerns and then a database for shared (lookup) data. This of course throw referential integrity out the window. Which maybe that doesn't really matter and that's just the "old guy" in me.

I realize the "where the data is stored" is really a non-issue to the client applications as they will be leveraging an API. However the API will be concerned with data storage. At this point I am trying to get some opinions on how to best structure the database(s) to conform to modern best practices of RDBMS systems.

Thanks for any and all recommendations.

-c

Answer (score 0):

(too big for a comment):

If you define the logical boundaries between each application (in practise, not theory) you might find you've answered your own question. Referential Integrity only affects related tables so if each apps data is different that shouldn't be a problem.

If using EF a context for each app and a context for the shared lookups is one approach. Julie Lerman explains EF Bounded Contexts (don't use one massive EF context, break it up) in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx), but ultimately a pragmatically normalised relational database should work fine for your requirements.

Comment: Yes most of the data is unique to each application. However there are a few pieces of information that are shared. For instance a Customer table that represents which one of our clients is serviced by each app and its functionality. One application is a procurement application, the other is a personnel application. I'd like to avoid having that a Customer table in each database. But I would also like to avoid one gigantic database with 200 tables in the end (as we bring other applications online). So a Customer table in a Common DB made more sense. But not if it's a bad design decision.Thanks

Comment: I often have databases with hundreds of tables because I still think it's simpler than managing multiple databases (and it's certainly cheaper). To get more specific recommendations I think you will need to provide the expected number of applications, how large each database will be, how you are hosting the database, recovery plans etc.. That's beyond my skill set I'm afraid - but might help you get the answer you are looking for